# bootmgr is missing on Toshiba laptop with Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, toshiba-laptop, bootmgr

I have a Toshiba laptop with Windows 7 on it. As soon as I turn my computer on it says

> bootmgr is missing

The only thing I can get into is the setup menu. Does anyone know what might be wrong? My step brother thinks that it might be that everything was erased off my hard drive. The last thing he did when he used it was to perform the Toshiba updates and restart the computer.

If anyone knows what might be wrong or how I could get my computer up and running please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about Windows 7, but on Vista it can apparently be sorted using the Windows disc if you have it

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/fixing-bootmgr-is-missing-error-while-trying-to-boot-windows-vista/

Answer (score 1):

To repair your BOOTMBR:

1. Put the Windows Vista or Windows 7 installation disc in the disc drive, and then start the computer.
2. Press a key when you are prompted.
3. Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard or an input method, and then click Next.
4. Click Repair your computer.
5. Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.
6. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.
7. Type "Bootrec.exe /FixMbr", and then press ENTER.

I've done this several times after having problems with Grub and linux installation.

Comment: I know I copied my answer from a different question, but the questions were exactly the same.